# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

The new design just launched for both the parent site and Meta. Congratulations!

If you see any styling or css bugs, please start a **new post**, and tag it with "design" and "bug" please. This way it'd be easier for me to track and fix.

Congrats again, and thank you for your design input and support!

**edit:** since this question gets asked quite often: here's how you manually refresh the new favicons if your browser caches the old one.

load these two in browser address bar, and do a hard refresh.

http://sstatic.net/photo/img/favicon.ico
http://sstatic.net/photometa/img/favicon.ico

Comment: Well done. This design is awesome.